# String to one_hot tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, session

I have found in tensorflow doc the following function to compute and apply a vocabulary onto a string tensor but it was still using `tf.session` and I can't make it work with `tf.function`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_transform as tft


@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),))
def string_to_one_hot(labels):
    codes = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(labels)
    return tf.one_hot(codes, depth=tf.cast(tf.reduce_max(codes), tf.int32))


test_labels = tf.constant(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'])
test_one_hot = string_to_one_hot(test_labels)

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'compute_and_apply_vocabulary/vocabulary/Placeholder' with dtype string
     [[node compute_and_apply_vocabulary/vocabulary/Placeholder (defined at /Users/clementwalter/.pyenv/versions/keras_fsl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_transform/analyzer_nodes.py:102) ]] [Op:__inference_string_to_one_hot_52]
```

### EDIT

I have been able to build such a function with direct use of the hash facilities. However I have had to use a hard-coded bucket_size/depth param. Any ideas?

```
@tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string),))
def string_to_one_hot(labels):
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.strings.to_hash_bucket_fast(labels, 1024), depth=1024)
    return tf.boolean_mask(one_hot, tf.reduce_sum(one_hot, axis=0) > 0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have found a proper answer:

```
def string_to_one_hot(labels):
    colnames, codes = tf.unique(support_labels_name)
    return colnames, tf.one_hot(codes, depth=tf.size(colnames))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I would use `tensorflow_transform` in conjunction with `tensorflow_data_validation` to do the one hot encoding for a feature named `oh` in `some.csv`. The steps are as follows:

1. Compute the statistics and infer the `SCHEMA` against your data.
2. Set up a `preprocessing_fn` that you will run via tensorflow transform/apache beam
3. Within `preprocessing_fn` figure out the depth of your one hot encoded feature (how many categories you're dealing with)
4. Create a feature that represents an index that maps these categories to integers
5. Pass this index feature to `tf.one_hot` and tell it what the depth is
6. Clean up the intermediary feature and returned the transformed "dictionary"

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
import tensorflow_transform as tfx
TRAIN_FILE_PATH='./some.csv'
train_stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_csv(data_location=TRAIN_FILE_PATH)
SCHEMA = tfdv.infer_schema(statistics=train_stats)

def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
    transformed = inputs.copy()
    oh_domain = tfdv.get_domain(SCHEMA, 'oh')
    oh_depth = len(oh_domain.value)
    transformed['ohi'] = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(transformed['oh'])
    transformed['oh_oh'] = tf.one_hot(transformed['ohi'], depth = oh_depth)
    del(transformed['ohi'])
    return transformed
```

The above is a "point" solution in the sense it just addresses how to do this specific thing.  The periphery to be optimized is only having tensor operations within `preprocessing_fn` which you can do with some functional programming tricks, and some other things which might sacrifice readability for performance.